# Probability over $50$-day ranges to predict results on one day

Tags: probability

The title is a bit complex, so I'll just post the question. This is in preparation for a final I'm going to take.

> Consider the total number of cars that a car dealership might sell over $50$ randomly selected (contiguous) days. Assume that the expected value of the number of cars sold over such a random sample of $50$ days is $62$ cars and that the standard deviation is $7$ cars.
>
> The question I'm having trouble with is: What can you say about the probability that the dealership sells more than $1$ car on a randomly selected day?

I answered that you can't say anything, because all you know is the probability for a sample of $50$ days, which means all the cars could theoretically be sold on one day, or they could be sold evenly over the course of $50$ days. Apparently, this answer is incomplete.

I can't figure out what you could possibly gather from the information given; any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can place upper and lower bounds on this probability. For instance, could the information be consistent with a probability of $1$? If so, then it is *certain* that at least one car will be sold each day. A quick check shows that the standard deviation could not approach $7$ (it cannot exceed $12\sqrt{1/50 \times 49/50}=1.68$). *Ergo,* the largish SD is imposing an upper bound on the probability. There is a lower bound on the probability, too.

Comment: Is the probability zero or > 0 ?

Comment: What formula is being used for calculating the upper SD for the 1/50 probability?

Answer (score -1):

Let $X$ be the demand over the 50-day period. Let $Y$ be the daily demand. Using the model $Y = {X \over 50}, $ we have $E[Y] = {62 \over 50} = 1.24$ and $\sigma_Y^2 = {\sigma_X^2 \over 2500}=0.0196,$ or $\sigma_Y = 0.14$

Now you are interested in $P[Y \geq 1]$. Instead, think about $P[Y \leq 1]$ and use Chebyshev's inequality. At $Y = 1,$ the number of standard deviations you are distant from the mean of 1.24 is ${0.24 \over 0.14} =1.7143 $ and using the one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality:

$P[Y \leq \mu - k \sigma ] \leq {1 \over k^2 +1} ,$ we find $P[Y \leq 1] \leq 0.2539$

Now convert that to the complementary

$P[Y \geq 1] > 0.7461$

Another model is to let the daily demand, call it $D_i,$ be such that the demand over the 50 days is $X = \sum D_i .$ If we assume the daily demands are independent, then we require $E[D_i] = {62 \over 50}$ and $\sigma^2_{D_i} = {49 \over 50} $ so the variance over the 50 day period will be $49.$

Following the same Chebyshev logic as in the first model, I find

$P[D_i \geq 1] > 0.0555$

Given the large difference and the even more extreme example whuber noted, can the OP get us more information?

Comment: You appear not to consider the possibility $P[Y=1]$.

Comment: Suppose there was a monster sale day on which 50 cars were sold, 12 other days on which just one car was sold, and no cars were sold the remaining 37 days. The SD is reasonably close to "7" (it is about 7.05), but the chance that "more than one car" was sold on any given day is just $1/50=0.02$, far less than your lower bound of $0.75$.

Comment: I've used the term "model" purposefully. Not all models are good ones. On a question like this we are trying to figure out what a professor wants. For example, another possibility is to model car sales as Poisson with daily expected demand of 1.24, which would give $P[Y \geq 1] = 0.7106$ Is it a better model? I would say it is lacking since it won't meet the known variance over the 50-day period.